# How to add weblogic-application.xml in a WAR file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, descriptor

Could you please let me know whether weblogic-application.xml can be added in a WAR file and if so, then how to do the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it cannot. If you do it, then it won't be considered.

It needs to be in an ear-file/META-INF

The weblogic-application.xml file is the WebLogic Server-specific deployment descriptor extension for the application.xml deployment descriptor from Sun Microsystems. This is where you configure features such as shared Java EE libraries referenced in the application and EJB caching.

This info is for WLS 10.3.x 
more details at:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/app_xml.htm#i1007581

Comment: How would someone then deploy a shared JAR and reference it from a WAR? weblogic.xml cannot be used because the library is a JAR and weblogic-application.xml cannot be used either because the app is a WAR. What then?

Comment: you cannot reference a shared jar file from weblogic.xml, but if you have a war shared file, then this could be referenced from your war file
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#WLPRG351

Answer (score 0):

The file is located in the META-INF subdirectory of the application archive.
Also go through this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/programming/app_xml.html) for more details.

Comment: see above, file is for EAR archives not WARs.